# How to decrement a Character that contains a digit?

Tags: swift, character

`c` is a Character variable in Swift that I happen to know contains a digit from 1 to 9. I want to decrement the value of the digit stored in `c`, and this is the best I could come up with:

```
c = Character(String(Int(String(c))! - 1))
```

Which seems insanely convoluted. Is there a better way?

Comment: Define "better"... :)

Comment: It's aesthetic preference I suppose, but going from a Character to a String to an Int to a String and finally back to a Character seems like it can't possibly be the best way. That's a hilariously ugly line of code, and having written it, "there must be a better way" immediately comes to mind. Ok, if not "better" (which is always going to be a matter of opinion on some level), how would you go about doing this?

Comment: Well as you say yourself I'm afraid it would just be a matter of opinion. If you're sure that `c` will always be what you expect, then the force unwrap is legit - I'm not sure what to improve then, other than cosmetic preferences... and that would be off-topic here indeed.

Comment: Using string interpolation makes it shorter, but I wouldn't say "better": `Character("\(Int("\(c)")! - 1)")`.

Comment: With that small a data set you could just define a dictionary that maps each character to the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a perfect use for `UnicodeScalar`:

```
let scalar = UnicodeScalar("8")
let char = Character(UnicodeScalar(scalar.value-1)) // "7"
```

Or, more verbosely from a character variable:

```
let c = Character("8")
let str = String(c)
if let scalar = str.unicodeScalars.first {
    let char = Character(UnicodeScalar(scalar.value-1)) // "7"
}
```

This is pretty messy, as we have to convert the `Character` into a `String`, then a `UnicodeScalar`, and then back to a `Character`.  I'll keep working for towards a better solution.

I've figured out why the UnicodeScalar constructor works with a String literal.

There is a private initializer for `_NSSimpleObjCType` (which conforms to `UnicodeScalar`) which takes a the first character of a String and passes it to the `rawValue` constructor.

[NSObjCRuntime.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/NSObjCRuntime.swift)

```
extension _NSSimpleObjCType {
    init?(_ v: UInt8) {
        self.init(rawValue: UnicodeScalar(v))
    }

    init?(_ v: String?) {
        if let rawValue = v?.unicodeScalars.first {
            self.init(rawValue: rawValue)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's weird that characters don't have an associated scalar value, but strings have scalar values for each character that makes up the string. Accessing and modifying the scalar value seems like a useful thing to do with characters. At least there's a way to do it but apparently it's necessary to convert to a string first.

Comment: @JSLigon Agreed!  I also don't know why passing in a single character String literal into a `UnicodeScalar` constructor works, but a Character or String variable reference does not.

Comment: @JSLigon I've edited my answer with an additional find from the open-source Swift implementation of `UnicodeScalar` in NSObjCRuntime.swift.  The constructor is basically doing what I do manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension as follow:

```
extension Character {
    var integerValue: Int {
        return Int(String(self)) ?? 0
    }
    var predecessor: Character {
        return integerValue.predecessor() < 0  ? "0" : String(integerValue.predecessor()).characters.first!
    }
}

var c: Character = "9"
c = c.predecessor  
print(c)  // "8"
```