# Extending UnicodeScalar: Creating an init method from a Character

Tags: ios, swift, unicode, character

This question was inspired by a similar question on how to decrement the ASCII value of a character in Swift: [How to decrement a Character that contains a digit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35489690/2415822)

The [`UnicodeScalar`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_UnicodeScalar_Structure/index.html) struct provides an interface to represent a [Unicode scalar value](http://www.unicode.org/glossary/#unicode_scalar_value) in Swift.  I am trying to extend `UnicodeScalar` and create an initializer that takes in a Swift `Character` and returns a `UnicodeScalar` value of that `Character`.

To create a `UnicodeScalar` from a `String` is very easy.  There is a private initializer for `_NSSimpleObjCType` (which conforms to `UnicodeScalar`) which takes a the first character of a String and passes it to the `rawValue` constructor.

[NSObjCRuntime.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/NSObjCRuntime.swift)

```
extension _NSSimpleObjCType {
    init?(_ v: UInt8) {
        self.init(rawValue: UnicodeScalar(v))
    }

    init?(_ v: String?) {
        if let rawValue = v?.unicodeScalars.first {
            self.init(rawValue: rawValue)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

The result:

```
let stringScalar = UnicodeScalar("8") // 56 (U+0038)
```

From a `Character` literal this is more verbose.  I need to manually convert the `Character` to a `String`, get its `unicodeScalars`, and return the first scalar in the array:

```
let c = Character("8")
let str = String(c)
if let scalar = str.unicodeScalars.first { // 56 (U+0038)
    // ...
}
```

My attempt at an `init` in an extension:

```
extension UnicodeScalar {

    init?(_ v: Character?) {
        if let rawValue = String(v).unicodeScalars.first {
            String(v).unicodeScalars.first
            self.init(rawValue)
        } else {
            return nil;
        }
    }
}
```

Testing this new init with "8" returns U+004F (`"O"`), when I would expect it to return `"8"` (U+0038).

```
let testChar = Character("8")
let scalar = UnicodeScalar(testChar) // U+004F
```

I've also tried calling the String initializer with `self.init(String(v))` in the `init` above, but I get the error `'UnicodeScalar.init' with an argument list of type '(String)'`.  I know this isn't the case since the `String` initializer is provided with the extension on `_NSSimpleObjCType`.

Where did my initializer fail?

Comment: I actually don't see the relation to _NSSimpleObjCType. "8" is a UnicodeScalarLiteralType, and `UnicodeScalar("8")` calls just `public init(_ v: UnicodeScalar)`. There is no UnicodeScalar initializer which takes a String (at least not in Xcode 7.2).

Comment: @MartinR `String` doesn't conform to `UnicodeScalar` and needs to use the extension to get the first character as a scalar, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @MartinR Oh I see what you're saying.  The literal is not a string.  That's why the literal conversion works but `let str = "h"; let scalar = UnicodeScalar(str)` doesn't.  I see my misunderstanding now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your init method

```
init?(_ v: Character?)
```

takes an *optional* character as parameter, therefore the string
interpolation `String(v)` returns the string

```
Optional("8")
```

with capital "O" as the first Unicode scalar ...

Changing the parameter type to a non-optional (or unwrapping
the parameter) should solve the problem.

Comment: ... I can't believe that.  I should just close this as a typo.  Thanks Martin.